# android to send text message without SMS Manager

Tags: android, sms

So I received an email from Google stating that they are now requiring all apps to become the default SMS/Phone provider in order to use SMS Manager and such. My app only sends a single text message when certain alerts happen, so writing a whole SMS program for this isn't ideal. I would just send it to my php and deal with it via gateway there, but the number that the text messages are sent to require the same phone number as the user or else they get rejected.

Link to the article: [Google Article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html)

In my current app, I use SMS manager to automatically send a text message on certain alerts, it requires no user interaction (except the run time permissions).

I have looked into SMS Intent, but that doesn't work with all SMS applications (IE Facebook messenger doesn't keep the body when the intent is received), so the user would have to manually type the alert and send it.

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

smsIntent.putExtra("address","5551234567");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "This is our test message!");
context.startActivity(smsIntent);
```

My question is that is there any other way to automatically send an SMS message without requiring the user to paste it, retype it or without `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false"/>`?

Comment: In Android doesn't need SMS Intent to send the SMS.

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj if you don't declare `SEND_SMS` permission in manifest, you get the following error `Sending SMS message: uid 10359 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS`, and starting Jan 2019 (from the article I posted) Google is making apps become the default app in order to use this permission. So I am trying to find another way to do what I currently do.

Comment: And they are saying that, It is unable to use another method. But you can pass the data that you need to send to the number to the SMS intent. So user no need to enter them manually

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj as I explained above, SMS intent doesn't work with all non default SMS apps, IE when you send the intent to facebook messenger, it doesn't carry over the body text.

Comment: Your code snippet is using `ACTION_VIEW`, which is not the correct action for sending an SMS as per the [documentation linked from the blog post](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage). Are you actually using `ACTION_VIEW` or using the correct Intent?

Comment: No. I think they are have mentioned to use SMS Intent as the Alternative.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using the correct intent at the moment, I posted that code to show what else I have tried, my current code is working great, but the SMS Intent doesn't automatically send a text, it just pops a box that lets the user push a button to send the SMS. Which isn't reliable as in my post Facebook ignores these intents, so if default SMS is Facebook messenger the body is blank.

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj that is what they are saying to use as an alternative, I know, that is why I am asking if there is something else, cause if you try to use SMS Intent with Facebook messenger as the default SMS app for example, Facebook ignores the intent and doesn't capture the body text that you send with the intent.

Comment: I think it is the issue with the Facebook Messenger. Not the Default SMS Intent.